# nginx root directive inside location block doesn't work

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

The current nginx conf I have looks like:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mydomain.com;

  root /home/myname/some_app/public;

  location / {
    try_files $uri @some_named_location;
  }

  location /sub {
    root /home/myname/other_app/public;
    try_files $uri @other_named_location;
  }
}
```

I expect `mydomain.com/sub/xxx` to be served by `/home/myname/other_app/public/sub/xxx`, but instead it's served by `/home/myname/some_app/public/sub/xxx`.  What's going wrong here?

I also tried using `alias` instead of `root` in the `/sub` location block:

```
location /sub {
  alias /home/myname/other_app/public;
  try_files $uri @other_named_location;
}
```

Then I expect `mydomain.com/sub/xxx` to be served by `/home/myname/other_app/public/xxx`, but still it's served by `/home/myname/some_app/public/sub/xxx`.

I even tried moving the server block's `root` directive into the `/` location block.

```
server {
  location / {
    root /home/myname/some_app/public;
    try_files $uri @some_named_location;
  }

  location /sub {
    root /home/myname/other_app/public;
    try_files $uri @other_named_location;
  }
}
```

But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Is `/home/myname/other_app/public/sub/xxx` a real file or is the `location @other_named_location` block invoked? What `root` is inherited by `@other_named_location`?

Comment: @RichardSmith `/home/myname/other_app/public/sub/xxx` is a real file.  The named location block is never invoked.  Sorry for the confusion.  I probably should simply use `=404` instead of `@xxx_named_location`.

Comment: Have you tried changing `some_app` to `other_app` as a test to ensure that you are editing the correct `server` block? Does the `server` block only contain these two `location` blocks? You should test the configuration using `nginx -T`.